# No encuentra la variable situada dentro de IF

Tags: java

¿Por qué devuelve error diciendo que no encuentra variable mensaje?:

**error: cannot find symbol mensaje**

Código:

```
public static void calculanotafinal(){
      double calificaciontotal = 85;

      if(calificaciontotal>=85){
      String mensaje = "Excelente trabajo";
      }

      System.out.println( mensaje );
}
```

Comment: creo que te equivocaste y escribiste una respuesta como una pregunta no?

Comment: Debes de declarar la variable fuera del `if`

Comment: no Juan. No se cómo mostrar esa variable fuera de la condicional sin que devuelva error. Un saludo.

Comment: declarando fuera de la condicional de la siguiente manera me sigue dando error: String mensaje;

Comment: declara la variable fuera del if, de esta forma  String mensaje="";

Comment: Pues inicia la variable. Es decir, dale un valor inicial. No puedes mostrar por pantalla un valor sin iniciar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que inicializarla `null`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  double calificaciontotal = 85;
  String mensaje =null;

  if(calificaciontotal>=85){
     mensaje = "Excelente trabajo";
  }
  System.out.println( mensaje );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te esta dando un error de compilación, ya que no encuentra lógico un `System.out.println(mensaje)`, dado que la variable mensaje no existe en ese ámbito (existe solo en el condicional if).

La solución es iniciarla arriba, con string vació o null.

```
      double calificaciontotal = 85;
      String mensaje = "";

      if(calificaciontotal>=85){
          mensaje = "Excelente trabajo";
      }

      System.out.println( mensaje );
```

Comment: Así es. Cometía el error de poner String de nuevo antes de la variable mensaje una vez dentro de la condicional. Ahora funciona perfecto con tu ejemplo. Gracias.